# Python web scraping problem. 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'head'

Tags: python

When I run my code I get this error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'head'
```

I don't know why. I want to get a result like this picture. Could you help me?

[image]

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
import pandas as pd
    

def getReviews(page_url):
    url = 'https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/soul_2020/reviews?type=top_critics'
    page = requests.get(url)
    if page.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    reviews= None
    
    for d in soup.findAll('div', attrs = {'class':'tabs__link js-tab-link js-tab-tracker'}):
        reviewer = d.find('a', attrs = {'class':'unstyled bold articleLink'})
        source = d.find('em', attrs = {'class':'subtle critic-publication'})
        content = d.find('div', attrs ={'class':'the_review'})
        date = d.find('div', attrs = {'class':'review-date subtle small'})
        score = d.find('div', attrs = {'class':'small subtle review-link'})
        
        all1 = []
        
        
        #reviewer    
        if reviewer is not None:
            all1.append(reviewer.text)
        elif reviewer is None:
            reviewer = d.find('a', attrs={'class':'unstyled bold articleLink'})
            if reviewer is not None:
                all1.append(reviewer.text)
            else:    
                all1.append(None)
        #source
        if source is not None:
            all1.append(source.text)
        else:
            all1.append(None)
        #content   
        if content is not None:
            all1.append(content.text)
        else:
            all.append(None)
        #date
        if date is not None:
            all1.append(date.text)
        else:
            all1.append(None)
        #score
        if score is not None:
            all1.append(score.text)
        else:
            all1.append(None)
        reviews.append(all1)
    return reviews

url = 'https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/soul_2020/reviews?type=top_critics'

reviews=getReviews(url)
print(reviews.head(5))
```